DataGrip - Unable to Resolve PL/SQL Cursors from Different Schemas in FOR CYCLE
I recently set up my DataGrip IDE and connected it to my database with introspection level set to 3. Everything seems to be working well—I can detect all objects, packages, tables, etc., from every schema. However, I’m encountering an issue with PL/SQL cursors used in FOR CYCLE statements.
Is there a fix for this, or is this a feature that needs to be addressed by JetBrains?
Thanks in advance for any assistance!
Scheme CORE is detected as you can see if using select or calling pkg right away from example
Here unable to resolve when using in FOR CYCLE with CURSOR
The schema is detected correctly when performing SELECT statements or calling packages directly (see the first screenshot), but cursors from different schemas are not being resolved when used in FOR CYCLE statements (see the second screenshot).
The code itself executes without issues in PL/SQL Developer, so the problem seems to be specific to DataGrip. I’ve tried using different Oracle dialects and Oracle+, but that didn’t help.

What excactly are you doing? What do you want to loop through? Your PL/SQL code looks wrong. If you want to loop through table IN_USERS, do something like this "FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM CORE.IN_USERS) LOOP ...."

As previously mentioned in the comment, it's unclear what you're trying to loop within a FOR loop. Please provide a full code example including a description of what you're trying to achieve.
